# Previous year value in ROW

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Executing this query:

```
SELECT        
    date, Sales, 
    SUM(Sales) OVER (PARTITION BY year(date)ORDER BY date) AS RunningTot
FROM            
    Sales
```

I get:

```
date            Sales           RunningTot
2017-12-31  36          36
2018-01-31  264248,48   264248,48
2018-02-28  234676,69   498925,17
2018-03-31  74393,17    573318,34
2018-04-30  82796,56    656114,9
2018-05-31  110964,21   767079,11
2018-06-30  230585,07   997664,18
2018-07-31  121234,79   1118898,97
2018-08-31  68654,07    1187553,04
2018-09-30  109911,46   1297464,5
2018-10-31  90233,16    1387697,66
2018-11-30  117970,76   1505668,42
2018-12-31  279867,84   1785536,26
2019-01-31  179425,87   179425,87
2019-02-28  100633,2    280059,07
2019-03-31  149884,95   429944,02
2019-04-30  191690,12   621634,14
2019-05-31  185345,89   806980,03
```

but I need to add a column with the previous year running total.
How can I do this?

I need something like this:

```
date            Sales           RunningTot  PYRunnTot
2017-12-31  36          36          NULL
2018-01-31  264248,48   264248,48   NULL
2018-02-28  234676,69   498925,17   NULL
2018-03-31  74393,17    573318,34   NULL
2018-04-30  82796,56    656114,9    NULL
2018-05-31  110964,21   767079,11   NULL
2018-06-30  230585,07   997664,18   NULL
2018-07-31  121234,79   1118898,97  NULL
2018-08-31  68654,07    1187553,04  NULL
2018-09-30  109911,46   1297464,5   NULL
2018-10-31  90233,16    1387697,66  NULL
2018-11-30  117970,76   1505668,42  NULL
2018-12-31  279867,84   1785536,26  36
2019-01-31  179425,87   179425,87   264248,48   
2019-02-28  100633,2    280059,07   498925,17   
2019-03-31  149884,95   429944,02   573318,34   
2019-04-30  191690,12   621634,14   656114,9    
2019-05-31  185345,89   806980,03   767079,11
```

Thanks

I tried to follow the steps provided in this Thread:
[SELECT previous year data based on year column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43105894/select-previous-year-data-based-on-year-column)

and using the LAG, but i cannot find a solution.

Thanks

Comment: It's very hard to read your data, please format it better

Comment: Please can you convert your data into example DDL/DML, ex: `DECLARE @Table TABLE (Column1 BIGINT, Column2 NVARCHAR(20)... );`   `INSERT INTO @Table (Column1, Column2...) VALUES (1, 'String'), (2, 'String2')...;`

Comment: Or create a sqlfiddle with your data

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reference the running totals twice - to do that you can use a CTE:

```
   WITH salesTotals
     AS (
 SELECT s.date
      , s.Sales
      , SUM(s.Sales) OVER(PARTITION BY year(date) ORDER BY s.date) AS RunningTot
   FROM Sales s
        )
 SELECT st.date
      , st.Sales
      , st.RunningTot
      , py.RunningTot AS PYRunnTot
   FROM salesTotals           st
   LEFT JOIN salesTotals      py ON py.date = dateadd(year, -1, st.date)
```